# How to clear screen/terminal in python

Tags: python, terminal

I have tried the commands to clear the terminal, for both Windows and Linux, but they are not working(I use a windows computer). This is my program:

```
print(1)

import os          # line 1
os.system('cls')   # line 2

print(1)
```

I have also tried using this:

```
import os
os.system('ls')
```

This code is also not working:

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

What else can I try to clear the python output terminal?

Comment: You must use 'cls'.

Comment: Please define "Not working" a bit better. Your code works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: It is not working in Python IDLE, though it is working in Visual Studio Code